# Integrating a function with two branch point $ {\int_{1}^\infty} \frac{dx}{{x(x^2-1)}^{1/2}} $

Tags: residue-calculus, branch-cuts, branch-points

I was studying a book about residue intigrating then I get into trouble solving this :
$ {\int_{1}^\infty} \frac{dx}{{x(x^2-1)}^{1/2}} $

I know that I have to choose a contour like this:
[image]

but I don't understand why integrating over $C2 , -C4 , C8 , -C6$ gives us same amounts so we can say : $4I=2\pi iRes(f,0)=2 \pi $ then $ I=\pi/2$
could you please help me with it ?

Comment: It's not the simplest way to evaluate the integral, but the idea is that you can define a branch $f$ of the integrand which is analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus ((-\infty, -1] \cup \{0\} \cup [1, \infty))$ and s.t. the integral of $f$ over $C_8$ approaches the original integral $I$ and the integral of $f$ over $C_6$ approaches $-I$. Note that $1/(x \sqrt {x^2 - 1})$ with the principal value of the square root does not have a pole at zero, so it's not the same as $f$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt$ using the *substitution* $x^2-1=t^2$.

Then define $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ and observe that it has *two simple poles* and $f(-z)=f(z)$.

Calculating $Res(f,i)=\frac{1}{2i}$ and defining $\alpha_R(t)=Re^{it}$ for $t \in [0,\pi]$ and $\gamma_R(t)=t$ for $t \in [-R,R]$ you have, thanks to the **Residue Theorem**:

$$\int_{\alpha_R*\gamma_R}f(z)dz=2\pi i Res(f,i)=\pi$$

Computing $\int_{\alpha_R}f(z)dz$, you can conclude $\lim\limits_{R \to +\infty}\int_{\alpha_R}f(z)dz=0$ and then you have:

$$\pi=\lim\limits_{R \to +\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt=2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt$$

Finally you get the result $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt=\frac \pi 2$

Comment: Wow! Such a cool trick to get rid of branch points!

Comment: @mahsa.e.1378 Tell me if you have any question.

Comment: Does such these trick always work? I mean if we had a problem that we had to use the contour I said , then how we could deal with ?

Comment: @mahsa.e.1378 I don't think it always works. In this case I tried to manipulate first the integral beacuse I didn't like the $\sqrt{x^2-1}$. I think that a general thing could be that you should first think how to traduce your function into a complex one, and then proceed to the computation.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful